# Is it possible to use conditions with NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations

Is it possible to impose conditions on the functions in `NDSolve`?

For example, consider:

$$f''(x)=-f(x)$$ with $f(x)<1$. Would it be possible to impose the inequality?

Comment: The question is confusing. With the i.c. $f(0)=0.5,f'(0)=1$ the solution is already determined, what result are you expecting? Some kind of _average_ between the solution and the inequality, or a `WhenEvent` that stops the calculation when the inequality is no longer satisfied, or something else?

Comment: @xzczd You are right, I shouldn't have imposed the i.c., I want my function to be always less than 1, would that be possible?

Comment: I think because `NDSolve` computes specific “particular solutions” (and exactly one in the case of a linear DE), you have to specify an IC.  There are infinitely many solutions with $f(x)<1$, and I don’t think `NDSolve` is built to handle that. With `DSolve`, one could try to compute the conditions on the parameters in the general solution that yield $f(x)<1$ for all $x$.  (“Always less than 1”, that is, “for all $x$,” is another problem for `NDSolve`, which solves over a finite domain. One could transform an infinite interval to a finite interval, I suppose, at least theoretically.)

Comment: What do you want to happen if `f[x]` tries to get `>1`?